# How can I calculate Christoffel symbols from this metric?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

I have a problem, I am given the following equation

$ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu=R_o^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta\cdot\bar{g}_{ab}(\varphi)d\varphi^ad\varphi^b)$

and I am asked to calculate the Christofell symbols of the metric $g_{\mu \nu}$ in terms of the metric $\bar{g}_{ab}$. I am told that the metric $g_{\mu \nu}$ is $N$-dimensional and that $\bar{g}_{ab}$ is $(N-1)$-dimensional and that only depends on $\varphi^a$.

I also need to calculate the Ricci and Riemann tensors of $g_{\mu \nu}$

How can i do it? Thank you everyone.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Andrew I have tried what InertialObserver has answered. My problem is that I don't know what to do with $\varphi^a$ and $\varphi^b$, because the metric $\bar{g_{ab}}$ depends only on $\varphi^a$. That's why I'm messing up when it comes to calculating $g_{\varphi \varphi}$. If I keep the two $\varphi$ separately it would become an antisymmetric metric but I don't know how to join them either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way to express the components of the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ you've written down
\begin{eqnarray}
g_{\theta\theta} &=& R_0^2 \\ 
g_{\theta a} &=& 0 \\
g_{ab} &=& \sin^2 \theta \bar{g}_{ab}(\varphi^c)
\end{eqnarray}
This yields the following inverse metric
\begin{eqnarray}
g^{\theta\theta} &=& \frac{1}{R_0^2} \\ 
g^{\theta a} &=& 0 \\
g^{ab} &=& \frac{1}{R_0^2 \sin^2 \theta} \bar{g}^{ab}
\end{eqnarray}
and the following derivatives
\begin{eqnarray}
\partial_\theta g_{\theta\theta} &=& \partial_a g_{\theta\theta} = 0  \\ 
\partial_\theta g_{\theta a} &=& \partial_b g_{\theta a} = 0 \\
\partial_\theta g_{ab} &=& R_0^2 \sin 2 \theta \bar{g}_{ab} \\
\partial_c g_{ab} &=& R_0^2 \sin^2\theta \partial_c \bar{g}_{ab}
\end{eqnarray}
The first step is to compute the Christoffel symbols. The general form is
\begin{equation}
\Gamma^\rho_{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2} g^{\rho \sigma}\left(\partial_\mu g_{\sigma\nu} + \partial_\nu g_{\sigma \mu} - \partial_\sigma g_{\mu\nu} \right)
\end{equation}
The components you need to calculate are

- $\Gamma^\theta_{\theta\theta}$
- $\Gamma^\theta_{a\theta} = \Gamma^\theta_{\theta a}$
- $\Gamma^\theta_{ab}$
- $\Gamma^a_{\theta\theta}$
- $\Gamma^a_{\theta b} = \Gamma^a_{b \theta}$
- $\Gamma^a_{bc}$

To calculate each one, plug $a, b, c$ or $\theta$ in for $\mu, \nu, \rho$ the general formula, sum over $\sigma=\{\theta, d\}$, and use the expressions above for the metric inverse and derivatives of the metric.

To do one example,
\begin{eqnarray}
\Gamma^\theta_{\theta \theta} &=& \frac{1}{2} \left[g^{\theta\theta} \left(\partial_\theta g_{\theta\theta} + \partial_\theta g_{\theta\theta} - \partial_\theta g_{\theta\theta}\right) + g^{\theta a} \left(...\right)_{a \theta\theta} \right] \\
&=& 0
\end{eqnarray}
In the first line, since $g^{\theta a}=0$, I didn't bother writing out all the terms in brackets explicitly. In the second line, since $\partial_\theta g_{\theta\theta}=0$, all the remaining terms are zero.

Once you have the Christoffel symbols, you can use the same approach to compute the non-zero Riemann tensor components, then by taking contractions of that you get the Ricci tensor and scalar. There will be a lot of algebra. Try to use symmetry arguments to reduce the number of calculations you need to do as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but recall that the equation for the Christoffel symbol $\Gamma$ is

$$
\Gamma_{cab} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_{b} g_{c a}+\partial_{a} g_{c b}-\partial_{c} g_{a b}\right). \tag{1}
$$

I think you're getting tripped up on the notation $\bar{g}_{ab}$, but just think of it as a coefficient $f_{ab}(\phi)$. The **definition** of the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ in equation (1) is defined through

$$ ds^2 = g_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu$$

so just find the metric using this definition and plug it into equation (1).

Comment: Okay, but, how could I calculate, for example, $g_{\varphi \varphi}$ to calculate Christoffel's symbols? My problem is that I don't know what to do with $\varphi^a$ and $\varphi^b$, because the metric $\bar{g_{ab}}$ depends only on $\varphi^a$. That's why I'm messing up when it comes to calculating $g_{\varphi \varphi}$. If I keep the two $\varphi$ separately it would become an antisymmetric metric but I don't know how to join them either.  . Thank you very much for your answer.

pd: I dont have enough reputation to vote your answer, sorry

Comment: @SrCuack Well if you're not told anything else about the problem then you just have to leave it as $g_{\phi\phi} \propto \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi ^2} \bar{g}_{\phi\phi}$